# how to solve three recursive equations, master method can not solve

Tags: recurrence-relations

$\begin{aligned}
&T(n) =3T(n-2)+logn  \\
&T(n) =T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor\right)+logn  \\
&T(n) =4T(n-1)+2^{n}+2T\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right) 
\end{aligned}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.